# WCF: The request to create a reliable session has been refused by the RM Destination

Tags: .net, wcf

I am facing an issue where from time to time users are getting the exception:

The request to create a reliable session has been refused by the RM Destination. Server 'xxx' is too busy to process this request. Try again later. The channel could not be opened.

The service is WCF running on .NET framework 4.7.2 using .nettcp binding in IIS 10.

I read up on reliable sessions (including several posts on StackOverflow) and saw that I can change the binding to increase MaxPendingChannels for a reliable session at server side. However when I change this in web.config the application cannot start, stating that property "MaxPendingChannels" is not known. I tried making a custom binding, but had the same result (app just would not start). It seems this property on ReliableSession is not known, but can't seem to find why that is.
Is there some dependency that needs to be installed or a certain version of a package before this property is useable in web.config?

I hope this is sufficient information and tanks for any input.

Comment: Microsoft's docs show examples of adding binding properties via code instead of configuration. Have you tried that?  Also, the docs indicate that it is part of ".NET Platform Extensions 7". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.reliablesessionbindingelement?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: Increase MaxPendingChannels attribute's value can solve this problem like this: `reliableSessionElement. MaxPendingChannels = 128`. If you can't start the program see if you have a detailed log.